# How can I run .Net 4.5 Web application on Windows 7 for end user which has .Net 3.5 by Default?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-7, asp.net-4.5

We have existing web application which is developed on .Net 3.5 but we wish to now upgrade it to .Net 4.5. But I want to make sure that it runs even on windows 7 OS without .Net framework 4.5. Is that possible with any workarounds?

Comment: What do you mean by web application. Does a web application even run on client side? Asp.Net is in my understanding just the server framework. The "web application" is then a normal webpage with HTML, CSS and so on.

Comment: Windows 7 comes with .Net 3.5 framework and our end users will have less or no connectivity to internet, and we have web application with .Net 4.5 as framework, will it run seamlessly without .Net 4.5 installed?

Comment: I was getting an error  **unable to install or run the application. the application requires version 4.5**. Will have end user install the offline installer for .Net 4.5. Anyways Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Then it is not a web application. It is a regular application and then you have no choice to either upgrade client-side or keep 3.5 on the development side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is NO. You'll need to install .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: The long answer is, an app written for .NET 3.5 might work with .NET 4.5, but not the other way around. What would be the benefit of upgrading, unless your app relies on some new goodness of .NET 4.5 which is consequently unavailable on older versions?

Comment: Newer versions have better support, security updates etc. So, I think it's always a good idea to upgrade gradually.